# React.js: filtering API object with 2 search bars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am fetching an API data set and filtering that data with a search bar to locate by first or last name. I also have an input field that allows you to add "tags" to the data set that I am mapping through. I am trying to add a second search bar to filter the original data by the unique tags as well, but can not figure out how to incorporate that information into the filter.

```html
export default function Home() {
    const [students, setStudents] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [showTests, setShowTests] = useState({});
    const [tagSearch, setTagSearch] = useState("");
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            try {
              const response = await axios.get(
                <!-- API -->
              );
              setStudents(response.data);
              setError(null);
            } catch (err) {
              setError(err.message);
              setStudents(null);
            } finally {
              setLoading(false);
            }
        };
        getData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="home-main">
            <Search setSearch={setSearch} />
            <TagSearch setTagSearch={setTagSearch} />
            {loading && <div>Loading, please wait ...</div>}
            {error && (
                <div>{`An Error has occurred. - ${error}`}</div>
            )}
            <div className="students">
                <Fragment>
                    {
                        students 
                        &&
                        students.students.filter((val) => {
                            if(search === '' || tagSearch === '') {
                                return val
                            } else if(val.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                            || val.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                            || tags.text.toLowerCase().includes(tagSearch.toLowerCase()) ){
                                return val
                            }
                        }).map(({val}) => (
                            
                            <!-- additional info -->
                            
                                    <div className="tags">
                                        <Tags setTags={setTags} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </Fragment>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is where the "tag" state is coming from...

```html
export default function Tags({setTags}) {
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
    const [tiles, setTiles]  = useState([]);

    const inputTextHandler = (e) => {
        setInputText(e.target.value);
    };

    const submitTagHandler = () => {
        setTiles([
            ...tiles, {text: inputText, id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)}
        ]);
        setTags([
            ...tiles, {text: inputText}
        ])
        setInputText('');
    };

    return (
        <div className="tags-main">
            <div className="tiles-contain">
                {
                    tiles.map((obj) => (
                        <Tiles key={obj.id} text={obj.text} id={obj.id} tiles={tiles} setTiles={setTiles} />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
            <input value={inputText} onChange={inputTextHandler} onKeyPress={(e) => {
                if(e.key === 'Enter') {
                    if(inputText !== "") {
                        submitTagHandler();
                    } else {
                        alert("Please enter a tag")
                    }
                };
            }} placeholder='Add Tag Here' type="text" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

It works without the tag state added to the filter. After adding the tag logic neither search bar works. How can I add the array of tags to the filter dependency to sort by first or last name and tags?

Comment: I believe that you are getting an error message in the console

Comment: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')" is the console error I'm getting which leads to the line the .filter else if statement starts on.

Comment: Because there is no such thing as `tags.text` because `tags` is an array and doesn't have property `text`. Check my answer below.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help. The error message is gone but it still doesn't filter by tag. I was trying to add the tag array to the API response being stored in the students state and trying to filter it that way as a work around. Does that sound like a reasonable thing to attempt?

Comment: @JackRackham can you provide the tags list as an example?

Comment: @NoumanRafique in the second code snippet after they are created with the **submitTagHandler()** function the format in which they are saved is **[ {text: "new tag"}, {text: "new new tag"} ]**

Comment: I just want to know how you `co-relate` tags with you data? For example, it i create a tag `name`. By name means, it should show result by filtering data that have some sort of key name. `tags.map(tag => tag.text.toLowerCase()).includes(tagSearch.toLowerCase())`. This just check `tags` whether it includes the `tagSearch` or not.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help. I think the primary problem I'm having is I don't know how to correlate the 2 sets of data. I implemented the **tags.map()** method into my code and it doesn't throw any errors but it also doesn't filter by that condition either.

Comment: I can give you an idea to co-relate both sets. Get all the keys of each record. Then loop through all the tags and check whether we the tag exist in those keys (By keys, i mean firstName, lastName). Then you can check if we have search text and compare it with the values of that object. There would be a better way to solve this. I just give my view to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you were getting an error "cannot read toLowerCase of undefined"

You probably wanted to do something like this

```
tags.some(tag => tag.text.toLowerCase() === tagSearch.toLowerCase())
```

or

```
tags.map(tag => tag.text.toLowerCase()).includes(tagSearch.toLowerCase())
```